# How can I most productively extract/relocate all files in multiple folders to one?

Tags: windows-10, folder-redirection

I fancy all music files from 
this Collection to be unified 
in one folder.  It's doubtless too 
unproductive to open each 
of the 68 folders.

How can I extract/relocate 
all files in these 68 folders 
to 'Pierre Boulez Complete 
Columbia Album"?

[image]

Comment: Enter proper mask (for example, *.mp3) into Search field (right-upper corner of Explorer window). Explorer will find all your files in all subfolders and show them as one filelist. Select all or a part of (may sort as needed) and move to the location which you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I merely copy and paste [Akina's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1501296/how-can-i-most-productively-extract-relocate-all-files-in-multiple-folders-to-on).

> Enter proper mask (for example, *.mp3) into Search field (right-upper corner of Explorer window). Explorer will find all your files in all subfolders and show them as one filelist. Select all or a part of (may sort as needed) and move to the location which you need. – [Akina](https://superuser.com/users/910710/akina) [Nov 12 '19 at 6:24](https://superuser.com/questions/1501296/how-can-i-most-productively-extract-relocate-all-files-in-multiple-folders-to-on#comment2266945_1501296)